# How to keep hl-line updated in inactive window?

Tags: compilation, hl-line-mode

I have `(setq global-hl-line-sticky-flag t)` to enable hl-line in all windows.  However, the highlighted line isn't updated when I change the cursor position in inactive window (e.g., by calling `next-error` to go to next error in the compilation buffer).

Comment: I have some custom functions that I run at the tail end of `compilation-goto-locus`.  It was several years ago that I added them, but I would imagine that I looked for hooks and thought that my solution was better.  You may wish to take a look at where `compilation-goto-locus` is called in the chain of events and decide whether that would be an appropriate place for you to force the update of highlighting that particular line.  Since it would be tail end of `compilation-goto-locus` that I am suggesting, an `advice` would be doable.

Comment: If you have not already done so, it would be helpful to read the doc-string for the variables `next-error-highlight` and `next-error-highlight-no-select`.  You may wish to disable `hl-line-mode` when jumping to next-error and use the built-in methods of the `compile` library to highlight or create a fringe arrow indicator in the source buffer.

Comment: I am having the same issue when using GUD for debugging.  I want the current line in the disassembler window to be highlighted when I "step instruction."  Right now the cursor moves automatically, but `hl-line` does not highlight the line where the cursor moved.

Comment: I arrived at the following solution for the GUD disassembly window: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45412/93.  It involves advising one of the gdb functions and explicitly invoking `hl-line-highlight`.  Not sure whether this is viable in your case or not.